# Python to exe compatibility error

Tags: python, compatibility, executable, x86-64

Hey StackOverflow community!
I'm new here and new to programming but I'm running into some trouble while doing things so let me explain.

I've tried to write a Python 2.7 script that my friends can run as an .exe, introduces itself when launched and asks the user if he/she wants to open a word document(outside the Python script in the same folder as the executable).
**It would be awesome if there is a way to continue the script when the user clicks on the console window again instead of having to use the sleep(8)+sleep(5) after opening the word document.**

After that it should explain some things about the word document and then the user gets the option to reply whatever they want to a question. The reply of which will be sent to my own mail after pressing enter(used a smtp for that).
After that they get the option to either close the script or read a lame joke that I still need to think of.

Ok that's all for the script that I had in mind.

Now I know that no friend of mine knows how to open a .py script, that's why I'm trying to make a regular executable for them(when the windows version is complete I still need a .app version for mac but that's a later concern).

I've used cx_Freeze to make that happen and worked my way through until all the stuff that I wanted to work actually worked.

The word document opens in word with the cx freeze version(don't know if there's a more general way for it then webbrowser.open but I don't know what path the files will be on my friend's their computers so I can't work with the subprocess one that actually points to a path) and everything else works as well.
Now I made this on a 64 bit Win 8.1 PC.
I've tested this on my other 32 bit Win 7 PC and it worked perfectly.
But when I sent it to my dad who also has a 32 bit Win 7 PC it showed a *"this version of file is not compatible with the version of windows you're running"* error. Now I've had my fair shares of compatibility errors with downloaded games so I tried to use different Win compatibility modes but nothing worked.

So now I've tried to make an .exe using pyinstaller(including pywin32 stuffs) and the same problem persists. It works on my PC but not on the 32 bit Win 7 PC from my dad.
Running it as admin didn't work, changing compatibility stuff didn't work, trying different .exe stuffs didn't work. So basically I ran out of ideas.

Can any of you help me please?
If I need to install things, for instance, to add 32 bit dependencies or something then I would like to request some steps to install it since I'm really new to this.

Here is my script:

```
import webbrowser
import smtplib
from time import sleep


def sendemail(from_addr, to_addr_list, cc_addr_list,
          subject, message,
          login, password,
          smtpserver='smtp.gmail.com:587'):
header  = 'From: %s\n' % from_addr
header += 'To: %s\n' % ','.join(to_addr_list)
header += 'Cc: %s\n' % ','.join(cc_addr_list)
header += 'Subject: %s\n\n' % subject
message = header + message

server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
server.starttls()
server.login(login,password)
problems = server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr_list, message)
server.quit()

print "Blabla test lines bla\n"

sleep(4)

check_one = raw_input("Open word thing now?(yes/no)")

if check_one == "yes":
    webbrowser.open("wordthing.doc")
    sleep(8)
    print "Done! bla"
if check_one == "no":
    print "Meh"

sleep(5)

print "blabla more bla"

sleep(3)

print ("The answer to the question below " 
       "will be mailed to my inbox \n")

sleep(2)


sendemail(from_addr    = 'thingthatmails@gmail.com', 
      to_addr_list = ['myownmail@gmail.com'],
      cc_addr_list = ['thingthatmails@gmail.com'], 
      subject      = 'Stack overflow question bla',
      message      = raw_input(" Is this a question?(yes/no) "), 
      login        = 'thingthatmails@gmail.com', 
      password     = 'thingthatmailspassword')


print "Mail sent!\n"

sleep(3)

print "Thanks for mailing blabla"

sleep(2)

print "Blablabla see you soon \n"

sleep(2)

close_script = raw_input("Type exit to close or ha! "
                        "for a lame ass joke > /n")


if close_script == "exit":
    print "Closing..."
    sleep(1)
if close_script == "ha!":
    print "badumm tss"
    sleep(2)
    print "..."
    sleep(1)
    print "I couldn't think of a joke here"
    sleep(1)
```

This is the setup.py I'm using to create an .exe with cx_Freeze:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup( name = "stackoverflow" , version = "0.1" , description = "test" ,      executables = [Executable("stackoverflow.py")] , )
```

This is the command I use in powershell to create an .exe with cx_Freeze:

C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py build

This is the command I use in powershell to create an .exe with pyinstaller:

python C:\pyinstaller-2.1\pyinstaller.py --onefile --console stackoverflow.py

Long post but I just wanted to make sure you have all the info you need :)
Thanks in advance, you would help me greatly to understand this a lot more!

Comment: If you're asking about 32bit vs 64bit compatibility, you'll have to uninstall python (64bit) and install the 32bit version. Then when you create your new .exe it should be able to run on 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even think of the python 64/32 installs. That did the trick with the compatibility. Is there a better way to open the word file other than webbrowser.open()?  and how do I rate your answer as good on here, I don't see that option available.
And is there a way to wait for the user to switch back to the console screen or not?

Comment: I just posted a comment, so you can't mark it, but you can upvote comments.

Comment: I just posted a comment, so you can't mark it as an answer, but you can upvote comments.  I'm not too sure about opening a doc file. I'm sure there is a better way to do it than that. You might have to do some research into opening files or including files within pyinstaller, etc.

Comment: Thank you Ryan! The main problem has been solved so that's a relieve haha. I'll research the options to open files. :)